# How to fix : The type Node is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <T>

Tags: java

i don't know how to solve this : The type Node is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments  ... also you can read it from the title. When i try to compile my program everything works fine, but i want solve that.
i have looked :

- [The type Stack is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Character>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551507/the-type-stack-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments-charac)
- [The type T is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <?> error in a generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066071/the-type-t-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments-error-i)
- [The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments [HTTPClient]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385961/the-type-list-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments-httpcli)

  ...
  and others but haven't find the solution or maybe im just dump to don't understand/get something.

i get that error anytime i declare node ex:

```
Node<Integer> node2 = null;//error on node Node<Integer>
        node2=new Node<Integer>(5, node2);//error on node Node<Integer>
        node2=new Node<Integer>(6, node2);//error on node Node<Integer>
        node2=new Node<Integer>(7, node2);//error on node Node<Integer>
```

Here is my node class :

```
// Nodo per realizzare liste concatenate.
public class Node<T> {
    // Elemento intero contenuto in questo nodo.
    private T elem;
    // Nodo successore, o null se e' l'ultimo nodo della lista concatenata.
    private Node  <T> next;

    // Crea un nuovo nodo con valore @elem e successore @next.
    public  Node  (T elem, Node  <T> next) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.next = next;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    // Ritorna l'elemento contenuto in questo nodo.
    public  T getElem() {
        return this.elem;
    }
    /**
     * @param p
     * @param q
     * @return boolean
     */
    public   boolean included(Node<T> p, Node <T> q) {
        boolean ret = true;
        boolean exit = false;
        Node<T> tempP = p;
        Node <T> tempQ = q;
        if (p == null || q == null) {
            if (q == null) {
                ret = false;
            }
            ret = true;
        } else {
            while (tempP != null && ret) {
                exit = false;
                while (tempQ != null && !exit) {
                    if (tempP.getElem() == tempQ.getElem()) {
                        exit = true;
                        tempQ = tempQ.next;
                    } else {
                        tempQ = tempQ.next;
                    }
                }
                tempP = tempP.next;
                if (exit) {
                    ret = true;
                } else {
                    ret = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * @param p
     * @param x
     * @return int Ritona un intero che rappresenta le occorenze di x nella lista p
     */

    public  int occurrences(Node <T> p, T x) {
        if (p.next == null)
            return (p.elem == x) ? 1 : 0;
        return findOcc(p, x, 0);
    }

    /**
     * @param p
     * @param x
     * @param i
     * @return int
     */
    private  int findOcc(Node<T> p, T x,int i) {
        int count = i;
        if (p.next == null) {
            return count = count + uguali(p.elem, x);
        } else {
            count = findOcc(p.next, x, count);
            count = count + uguali(p.elem, x);
            return count;
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param elem
     * @param x
     * @return int
     */
    private   int uguali(T elem, T x) {
        return (elem == x) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * @param p
     * @return Node
     */
    public Node <T> reverse(Node<T> p) {
        Node <T> ret = null;
        Node<T> tempP=p;
        ret = reverse(tempP, ret);
        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * @param p
     * @param ret
     * @return Node
     */
    private  Node <T> reverse(Node <T> p, Node<T>  ret) {
        Node <T> retElem = ret;
        if (p.next == null) {
            return new Node<T>(p.elem, retElem);
        } else {
            retElem = new Node<T>(p.elem, retElem);
            retElem = reverse(p.next, retElem);
            return retElem;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param elem Cambia l'intero contenuto nel nodo al nuovo valore @elem.
     */

    public void setElem(T elem) {
        this.elem = elem;
    }

    /**
     * @return Node Ritorna il riferimento al nodo successore, oppure null se non
     *         c'e' un successore.
     */

    public  Node<T> getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    /**
     * @param next Cambia il riferimento al nodo successore con @next.
     */

    public void setNext(Node <T>next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
     
    public  int getSize(){
        return getSize(this) ;
    }
    
    private int getSize(Node<T> node) {
        return node==null?0:1+getSize(node.getNext());
    }

    public Node<T> listsLeng(Node<T> p){
        Node<T> ret = null;
        Node<T> temp=p;
        int size;
        while(temp!=null){
            size=getSize((Node<T>)temp.getElem());
            ret = new Node(size, ret);
            temp=temp.getNext();
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public void print() {
        Node<T>  ret = this;
        print(ret);
    }
    
    /** 
     * @param p
     */
    public void print(Node<T> p){
       if(p.getNext()==null){
        System.out.println(p.getElem());
       }else{
        print(p.getNext());
        System.out.println(p.getElem());
       }

    }
}
```

if you want see try to see yourself : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YkOQYtZIoipW996c3PhNCY_pfhdMctw8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you get the error outside of the Node class? Is it possible the name is being shadowed?

Comment: As @user suggests you should omit `<T>` in method signatures like `public  <T> boolean included(Node<T> p, Node <T> q)`. Otherwise you hide the generic type of Node..

Comment: yes i get the error outside of the class , not in node. ex in the test class i get the error or everywhere i declare node. Also everything work fine if i compile i get the output i wanted .

Comment: @MichaelKreutz you're right, but shadowing the type parameter shouldn't make the type `Node` itself shadowed. I have a feeling there is another `Node` imported from somewhere else

Comment: @MichaelKreutz So do you mean to remove <T> llike  public  boolean included(Node<T> p, Node <T> q) ?

Comment: please remove all such occurences in method signatures. Besides, you could share your import statements. To be sure that you are not accidentially taking a different class as @user points out

Comment: @MichaelKreutz i removed all <T> and still getting the same error , i have no imports

Comment: can you please update the `Node` class in your question. No imports in the class where you see this error?

Comment: @MichaelKreutz updated  and added a link to all files so you can see yourself , try to compile with javac from cmd or maybe you can see the error from your idee , i'm using vs code

Comment: @Si In the OP you state "When i try to compile my program everything works fine" but the last comment says that you see the error when you compile.

Comment: @vsfDawg yes everything works fine , i see only this Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.   if i compile with javac from cmd , otherwise i don't see it ... only the idee shows the error . Also can't get why downvote ?

Comment: @Singh check the imports on the class throwing the Exception and make sure that it is picking up the correct Node class.

Comment: @vsfDawg as i stated there are no imports and there is only one node class

Comment: @Singh can you check my answer? you are doing a bad cast

Comment: The code looks good to me. Try to clean up the project and recompile your `Node` class.

Comment: @Singh are Node and the class throwing the exception in the same package?

Comment: @vsfDawg when i declare Node<Type> ... in any other class ex in my testing class i get the error , same package

Answer (score 2):

You try to cast `size=getSize((Node<T>)temp.getElem());` but `temp.getElem()` is of type `T`, it is not a `Node<T>`. 
In addition in the next line in `ret = new Node(size, ret);` you create a raw node and try to put `size` of type `int` into your generic `Node`. You should rethink about the method `public Node<T> listsLeng(Node<T> p)`.

EDIT: Also in `equals` of other classes (`Set` and `DynamicQueue`) you do unsafe casts. And in `TestDynamicQueue` you do `Node<Node>` where the inner Node is raw (not parametrized).

Comment: nothing changes, i have commented that section and same error. but now when i compile with javac from cmd i don't get " Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. "thats nice ahah.

Comment: saw it , ill fix that method , but i had commented all the method , the error remains

Comment: I updated again. It might come from other places of your code.